# Sort linq query by static dictionary value

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

For my application I would like to sort my `Item` entities by a static dictionary value depending on current `Item` type.
No matter what I try I just can not make it work, always getting an error saying:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[MyApp.Models.Item+ItemTypeE, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Here is my repository method trying to sort the `Item` entities:

```
private IOrderedQueryable<Item> Sort(IQueryable<Item> items)
{
    return items.OrderBy(i => i.Type)
                .ThenBy(i => 
                    Item.MyDic.Keys.Any(key => key == i.Type)
                    ? Item.MyDic[i.Type].Item2
                    : -1);
}
```

And the `Item` class:

```
public partial class Item : CavalenaEntity, ICavalenaEntity
{
    public enum ItemTypeE
    {
        Type1 = 0,
        Type2 = 1,
        ...
    }

    public static Dictionary<ItemTypeE, Tuple<int, int>> MyDic = new Dictionary<ItemTypeE, Tuple<int, int>>()
    {
        { ItemTypeE.Type1, new Tuple<int, int>(0, 1) },
        { ItemTypeE.Type2, new Tuple<int, int>(1, 100) },
        ...
    }
}
```

`Item.MyDic.Keys.Any(key => key == i.Type)` is working fine but I could not find a way to achieve something like `Item.MyDic[i.Type].Item2`.
I tried selecting `KeyValuePair` into a new anonymous object, also tried using `selectMany` but I still can not make it work.

If anyone could show me a way of achieving such a query I would be really grateful.
Thanks a lot.

***Final solution***

```
public IPagedList<Item> GetSoldableItems(Item.SortableTypeE sortName, SortOrder.TypeE sortOrder, int pageNb)
    {
        var items = entities.Items.Where(i => ...);

        var orderedItems = Sort(items.AsEnumerable(), sortName, sortOrder).ToList();

        return orderedItems.ToPagedList(pageNb, 10);
    }

    private IOrderedEnumerable<Item> Sort(IEnumerable<Item> items, Item.SortableTypeE sortName, SortOrder.TypeE sortOrder)
    {
        IOrderedEnumerable<Item> result = null;

        switch(sortName)
        {
            case Item.SortableTypeE.Type:
                result = sortOrder == SortOrder.TypeE.ASC
                    ? items.OrderBy(i => i.Type)
                    : items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Type);
                result = result.ThenBy(i => 
                        Item.MyDisc.ContainsKey(i.Type)
                        ? Item.MyDisc[i.Type].Item2
                        : -1)
                    .ThenByDescending(i => i.Bonus);
                break;
             ...
             default: break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the provider is trying to translate the query into SQL and it is failing to do that because you're using a local in-memory dictionary in your sorting logic. The solution for that is to drag the data and sort it in-memory. Since there is no filtering here, this should be fine from the performance side:

```
private IEnumerable<Item> Sort(IQueryable<Item> items)
{
    return items.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(i => i.Type)
                                .ThenBy(i => Item.MyDic.Keys.Any(key => key == i.Type)
                                            ? Item.MyDic[i.Type].Item2: -1);
}
```

Note for other cases: avoid using `AsEnumerable()` when there is a filtering logic after it, because that way you'll not be filtering on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However the whole thing is actually quite big, taking lots of criteria as parameter, sort columns ans sort orders. The `sort` method I posted is actually called right after a filtering and depends on sort column and order. I simplified the post because I did not think it could be important since the issue is only about getting the dictionary value. In addition, the `Item` table could possibly have lots of rows. Is it still ok to use `AsEnumerable()` ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: @Flash_Back Since you're filtering before, then there is no performance impact that can be noticed. As for any other way, then no! You can't use a local dictionary in an SQL Translated Linq Query. Think about it, this query needed to be translated into pure SQL, how can the provider do that when  you have a local key-value pair dictionary with custom types and tuples ! If you really need to execute everything on the server side, then write a stored procedure and call it using Linq and then map the results into objects. But this is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I was actually afraid about performances but what you say definitely makes sens, there should not be any problem since the filtering is done before. Thanks a lot for your explanation I understand it better now ;)

Comment: @Flash_Back Luckily you have no server side paging (`Skip` / `While`) related to ordering, so the above solution is just fine.  As a side note, if you really care about the performance, don't use code like `Item.MyDic.Keys.Any(key => key == i.Type)`, but `Item.MyDic.ContainsKey(i.Type)`.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: Hello Ivan, you posted on almost all my last questions I thank you a lot ! Initially I used `ContainsKey` but since Linq complained about it I just changed it into `Any`. With `AsEnumerable` I will be able to get back to `ContainsKey`. Unluckily I actually do have paging right after sorting, using `PagedList` library; `return items.ToPagedList(pageNb, 10);`. Will it cause serious performance issues coupled with `AsEnumerable` ?

Comment: Hi Flash, you are welcome :) Regarding using `IEnumerable` with `PagedList`. Most probably you'll have performance issues because the query will be reexecuted for every page, reading the whole data set in memory and then taking the page data. This does not happen with real `IQueryable`. One way is to materialize the result (using `ToList`) before passing to `PagedList`, but note that this will cause the `PagedList` to work with "snapshot" of the data, i.e. it wil not see the modifications, additions and deletions.

Comment: It's a pleasure to read you, you already helped me out building complex filtering using `PredicateUtils`, I am very grateful. I think that in this context the snapshot is not a problem. So would the solution just be to replace `AsEnumerable` by `ToList` in `user3185569` answer ? Will I be able to sort by my static dictionary value and avoid performance issues ?

Comment: It's better to apply it at the **end** (after ordering). The answer already handles the sorting, so this will just "fix" the result which then will be used for paging. So either insert `.ToList()` before last `;`, or do that at the call site - `var result = Sort(items).ToList();`.

Comment: Ok thanks again, I just edited the first post with what I understood to be the final solution. Is that right ? Won't performance be awful with both `AsEnumerable` and `ToList` ?

Comment: It's not awful because `AsEnumerable()` is solving the custom sort issue and `ToList()` is solving the performance issue introduced by the previous :) So the final solution should be just fine under those constraints. Cheers. Btw, @user3185569, please take my apologies for doing that discussion under your post.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And my apologies to User3185569 too. Thanks a lot to both of you for helping me out !